# UWP: How to write a umlaut in uppercase

Tags: c#, xaml, character, uwp, uwp-xaml

I would like to write umlauts in uppercase, but it doesn't work in the textbox for UWP apps. I have also added the language property in the textbox.

```
<TextBox x:Name="tbxDescription" Height="100" Language="de-CH" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.DetailTime.Beschreibung, Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" IsEnabled="{x:Bind ViewModel.DetailTime.Abgeschlossen, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource inverseBoolConverter}}"/>
```

It also doesn't work in the Edge Browser, finance app or the weather UWP. The language and the region settings from windows 10 I have also in german ("de-CH").

[image: Here I tried to add the language settings, but it didn't help]

[image: For example the weather app]

[image: Language settings in german]

Sorry for my bad english skills!

Update it doesn't work with the Swiss German keyboard layout!
[image]

Comment: I installed the German language and keyboard and am able to type "Ü" (via the on-screen keyboard) just fine into Edge and the Weather app. It should just work? Do you have a German keyboard? Could you explain how you're inputting the "Ü"? Is it only for UWP apps? Maybe it's a problem with your system and not programming-related.

Comment: I tested it in the `Textbox` of UWP and with touch keyboard, you can check the [result here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD3c1.png), so basically it's your system issue...

Comment: Thank you so it work with the German keyboard layout but with the Swiss German layout it doesn't work.